# Serialising a ray future and returning the results later

Tags: python, ray

I've wrapped Ray in a web API (using `ray start --head` and uvicorn with `ray.init`). Now I'm trying to:

1. Submit a job to Ray (via the API) and serialise the future and return to the user
2. Later, let the user hit an API to see if the task is finished and return the results

The kicker is that being a multi-thread I can't guarantee that the next call will be from the same thread. Here is what I naively though would work:

```
id = my_function.remote()
id_hex = id.hex()
```

Then in another request/invocation:

```
id = ray._raylet.ObjectID(binascii.unhexlify(id_hex))
ray.get(id)
```

Now this never gets finished (it times out) even though I know the future is finished and that the code works if I run it in the same thread as the original request.

I'm guessing this has to do with using another initialisation of Ray.

Is there anyway to force Ray to "refresh" a futures result from Redis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting objectID directly in your way can cause unexpected behaviors because of Ray's ref counting / optimization mechanism. One recommendation is to use "detached actor". You can create a detached actor and delegate the call in there. Detached actors will survive in the lifetime of Ray (unless you kill it), so you don't need to worry about problems you mentioned. Yes. It can make the program a bit slower as it requires 2 hops, but I guess this overhead wouldn't matter for your workload (client submission model).

https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=detached#detached-actors

```py
ray.remote
class TaskInvocator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.futures = {}
    def your_function(self):
        object_id = real_function.remote()
        self.futures[object_id.hex()] = object_id
    def get_result(self, hex_object_id):
        return ray.get(self.futures[hex_object_id])

TaskInvocator.remote(detached=True, name='invocator-1')
task_invocator = ray.util.get_actor('invocator-1')
object_id = task_invocator.your_function.remote()
blah blah...
result = ray.get(task_invocator.get_result.remote(object_id.hex()))
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-dept response and sample code. Thank you for the link to the documentation, I thought I had read every page in and out but I didn't grasp the idea of detached actors :)

Answer (score 1):

Serializing a ray future to a string out-of-band and then deserializing it is not supported. The reason for this is because these futures are more than just IDs, they have a lot of state associated with them in various system components.

One thing you could do to support this type of API is have an actor that manages the lifetime of these tasks. When you start the task, you pass its ObjectID to the actor. Then, when a user hits the endpoint to check if it's finished, it pings the actor which looks up the corresponding ObjectID and calls ray.wait() on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)